# Programmatically push values into an empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to push values into an empty `object`? I have here is a list of countries displaying the country name and population. I want to insert those values into an object much like the example below.

```
<ul class="countries">
    <li  class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
        <span class="country-population">200</span>
        <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
    </li>
    <li class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
         <span class="country-population">200</span>
         <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
     </li>
     <li class="country">
         <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
         <span class="country-population">400</span>
         <span class="country-population">Blablabla</span>
     </li>

</ul>
```

---

```
var countries = [
    {name: "Philippines", population: 200, description: "Blablabla"},
    {name: "Brunei", population: 200, description: "Tatatata"},
    {name: "Malaysia", population:4100, description: 'Zzazazaza'}
]
```

---

```
0: {name: "Philippines", population: 200, description: "Blablabla"}
1: {name: "Brunei", population: 200, description: "Tatatata"}
2: {name: "Malaysia", population: 400, description: "Zzazazaza"}
```

I tried the script below but only inserts the name of the country. How can also insert the `population` and `description` values?

```
var countries_new = [];

$('.countries > .country > .country-name').each(function() {
    countries_new.push({
        name: $(this).text()                
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the `.country` elements instead, then `find` the elements within **each** `.country` with the other information. As per mock array, `population` seems to be a **number** and `text()` returns **string**, use `Number()` to convert it.

```js
var countries_new = [];

$('.countries > .country').each(function() {
    countries_new.push({
        name: $(this).find(".country-name").text(),
        population: Number($(this).find(".country-population").text()),
        description: $(this).find(".description").text()
    });
});

console.log(countries_new);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="countries">
        <li  class="country">
            <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
            <span class="country-population">200</span>
            <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
        </li>
        <li class="country">
            <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
            <span class="country-population">200</span>
            <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
        </li>
        <li class="country">
            <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
            <span class="country-population">400</span>
            <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Always best to say *what* you did, and *why*, rather than just dumping code.

Comment: Wrote the same, but a second to late :D To the why: You need to select the parent element, since you want to use all children in it. Would work with siblings(), too but this solution is nicer

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Added :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `find()` to get the reference of each context inside the loop. Also notice that `+` which is prefixed to change that text to a number type. You can also use `parseInt()` there. Using `trim()` will be helpful to remove extra leading and trailing whitespaces in the objects.

```js
var countries = [];
$('.countries .country').each(function(){
  var countryRef = $(this);
  countries.push({
    name: countryRef.find('.country-name').text().trim(),
    population: +(countryRef.find('.country-population').text().trim()),
    description: countryRef.find('.description').text().trim()
  });
});
console.log(countries);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="countries">
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
    <span class="country-population">200</span>
    <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
  </li>
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
    <span class="country-population">200</span>
    <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
  </li>
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
    <span class="country-population">400</span>
    <span class="country-population">Blablabla</span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this, just select all countries and from that element select the values you want:

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.countries>.country')].map(
    (el) => ({
      name: el.querySelector('.country-name').innerText.trim(),
      population: el.querySelector('.country-population')
        .innerText.trim(),
      description: el.querySelector('.description')
        .innerText.trim(),
    }),
  ),
);
```

```html
<ul class="countries">
    <li  class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
        <span class="country-population">200</span>
        <span class="description">P Blablabla</span>
    </li>
    <li class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
        <span class="country-population">200</span>
        <span class="description">B Blablabla</span>
    </li>
    <li class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
        <span class="country-population">400</span>
        <span class="description">M Blablabla</span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your `span` elements have CSS classes starting with `country-` this would be a generic approach:

```js
const countries = document.querySelectorAll('.country');

const result = [];

for (const country of countries) {
  let resEl = {};
  [...country.querySelectorAll('span[class^="country-"]')].forEach((span) => resEl[span.className.split('-')[1]] = span.innerText)
  result.push(resEl);
}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<ul class="countries">
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
    <span class="country-population">200</span>
    <span class="country-description">Blablabla</span>
  </li>
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
    <span class="country-population">200</span>
    <span class="country-description">Blablabla</span>
  </li>
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
    <span class="country-population">400</span>
    <span class="country-description">Blablabla</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually not push  **values into an empty object** , you will rather like to create an object and push that object inside an array. So basically you can use array map method which will return an array.

With only javascript you can use `document.querySelectorAll` which will select all the elements with specified selector( class in this case) .`[...]` is using spread syntax to convert a live collection to array so that array methods can be use. Here map is an array method. Inside this method create an object and return that

```js
let k = [...document.querySelectorAll('.country')].map(function(curr) {
  return {
    name: curr.querySelector('.country-name').textContent.trim(),
    population: curr.querySelector('.country-population').textContent.trim(),
    description: curr.querySelector('.description').textContent.trim()

  }
})

console.log(k)
```

```html
<ul class="countries">
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
    <span class="country-population">200</span>
    <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
  </li>
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
    <span class="country-population">200</span>
    <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
  </li>
  <li class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
    <span class="country-population">400</span>
    <span class="description">Blablabla</span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach short but effective.

```
"use strict";
function _toConsumableArray(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    for (var b = 0, c = Array(a.length); b < a.length; b++) c[b] = a[b];
    return c;
  }
  return Array.from(a);
}
var results = []
  .concat(_toConsumableArray(document.querySelectorAll(".countries>.country")))
  .map(function(a) {
    return {
      name: a.querySelector(".country-name").innerText.trim(),
      population: a.querySelector(".country-population").innerText.trim(),
      description: a.querySelector(".description").innerText.trim()
    };
  });
console.log(results);
```

Comment: This has been posted three times already (actually, four, but then I saw the earlier ones and deleted mine). (And it's always best to say *what* you did, and *why*, rather than just dumping code.)

Comment: i am writing a code in my code file thats why it is taking a time.

Comment: as  you can see there is time saving line in my code. its not a copy paste @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I'm not saying you copied and pasted it. I'm saying there's no point to adding Yet Another Copy of the same answer (written originally or not). That's why I deleted mine when I saw two others. (Which also had your "time saving" difference -- I just suggested it on a previous version, since it doesn't appreciably save time with `this`.) When you see you've just duplicated a previous answer, delete the answer. It serves no purpose to leave it lying around cluttering things up.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for suggestion. i was lil late to post it. as i am writing my code.